# solve this equation for x : $27^x - 43^x -9^{(\frac{1}{2}+x)}=0$

Tags: exponential-function

solve this equation for x : $27^x - 43^x -9^{(\frac{1}{2}+x)}=0$ how can we solve this equation? I tried to find it graphically but I found a plenty of intersection points with the axis, how can we express these points.

Comment: Is that $4\cdot 3^x$?

Comment: no it's forty three

Comment: Where did you take it from?

Comment: from my classroom.

Comment: What does that mean? Did the teacher write it up or from book...

Comment: the teacher write it up.

Comment: Ask your friends if they also have 43

Comment: Yes I asked them :)

Comment: Ok, then ask the teacher. You do have his/her email?

Comment: unfortunately, I haven't his email.

Comment: How do you know he didn't write $4\cdot 3^x$? If I write this down you can hardly say if it is $43^x$ or $4\cdot 3^x$.

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: Can you try solving it?

Comment: @Mario Aqua is saying that you may be misinterpreting the problem. If the middle term is $4\cdot 3^x$, the problem has a "relatively nice" result. If the middle term is $43^x$, the problem does *not* have a "relatively nice" result. So, if you have only been looking at problems with "nice" results, it is more likely that you have a typo, and the problem is actually what Aqua suggests.

Comment: I did, can you answer the previous question please?

Comment: Ok can we suppose that the middle term is $43^x$

Comment: what will be the first value of x at which the equation will equal to zero

Comment: @Aqua which question that you want me to answer it

Comment: If the middle term is $43^x$, then it has no real solutions: [Wolframalpha shows no real solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x%3A+27%5Ex-43%5Ex-3*9%5Ex%3D0+over+reals)  Do you want Complex solutions?

Comment: The probability that the middle term is $4\cdot3^x$ is $100\%$. Listen to InterstellarProbe and Aqua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\to-\infty$, $f(x)=27^x-43^x-9^{\tfrac{1}{2}+x}$ goes to $0$. If you take the derivative of $f(x)$, it is easy to show that it is negative everywhere, hence, $f(x)$ is a decreasing function. This means that $f$ will always be less than zero for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so there are no real solutions. If you are looking for complex solutions, I suggest you to rewrite $x=a+bi$, use Euler's formula and proceed from there.

Comment: Well, B. Goddard answer is much more elementary. I don't know why you are not accepting his solution? @Mario

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Make a substitution $t=3^x$, then you get:

$$t^3-4t-3t^2=0$$

I suppose you can finish it now...

---

If that is realy $43$ then just draw the graph of $f(x)= 27^x - 43^x -9^{(\frac{1}{2}+x)}$ say in Geogebra and you will see the result. And it seems it does not have a solution in that case: [image]

Comment: I find the answer is $x=-\infty$ in the $43$ case

Comment: I did, I found this : https://ibb.co/fqXZ5hH

Comment: i can write the answer as a domain form (x,-infinity) x is the first point that has y = 0

Comment: And i'm searching about the first point

Comment: "i can write the answer as a domain form (x,-infinity) x is the first point that has y = 0"  Why on earth are you assuming there is a point $\alpha$ so that for all $x < \alpha$ then $y= f(x) = 0$.  There's utterly no reason to assume that at all.  And many have pointed out there are *no* points $x$ where $f(x) =0$.

Answer (score 3):

Divide through by $9^x$:

$$3^x - \left(\frac{43}{9}\right)^x = 3.$$

For $x>0$, the left side is negative, so it can't equal $3$.  For $x<0$, both $3^x$ and $(49/9)^x$ are between $0$ and $1$, so their difference can't be $3$.  There is no real solution to your equation.